# Java: optimizing GC for large buffers

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection

Application I am working on is simultaneously filtering huge files using heap memory only for *BufferedReader* buffers (~8Gb for multiple files). There is plenty of memory for a single filtering opreration to complete and then buffers are discarded:

```
try (BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
      new FileInputStream(file1), encoding), 1_000_000_000);

    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
      new FileInputStream(file2), encoding), 1_000_000_000);

    ...

    BufferedReader br8 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
      new FileInputStream(file8), encoding), 1_000_000_000);
```

) {

```
  // ... filtering

}
```

What should be optimal GC settings for this memory usage configuration?

Current JVM options are pretty standard:

```
-Xms31g
-Xmx31g
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:NewSize=12g
```

Java version is 9.

Comment: Do you really need a buffer that big? It seems at least 3 orders of magnitude too large to be of any real use. The default buffer is after all 8K, and provides very good performance.

Comment: Looks like you actually want to try memory mapped I/O. Measure speed. Maybe do your own alloc with flexible sizes on one huge buffer, size flexible to number of files.

Comment: @Kayaman Buffer size helps both performance and disk health, if reading multiple files simultaneously.

Comment: ..and since everyone knows that bigger is better, an internal `1GB` buffer for a `BufferedReader` is at least 1000 better than an internal `1MB` buffer, let alone the pathetic `8KB` buffer that it has by default. You should probably increase the buffer size. I mean you could still double that before it hits the array size limit.

Comment: Your are fixing it at the wrong end. You should use a large(r) target array when calling `Reader.read`. That makes using `BufferedReader` entirely obsolete. Further, the number of actual I/O operation is determined by the buffer size of the `InputStreamReader`’s decoder. The only way to control that is to use [`FileChannel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) and [`Channels.newReader(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html#newReader-java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel-java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder-int-)

Comment: On the other hand, as hinted by Joop Eggen, using memory mapped I/O may solve this even better.